# Emit value of integer when the difference between it and the previous is > 2

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

I have Flow emit the value of integer and I want to ignore the value when the difference between the current emission and the previous > 2

```
fun main() {
  GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
    flowOf(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 8, 12, 1)
    .distinctUntilChanged{new,old->
     ( new - old) >= 2
    }
   .collect { println(" emitted: $it") }
  }
}
```

I'm expecting 1,4,8,12

Comment: You wrote what you expected, but what you get?

Answer (score 1):

You used the correct function, but you messed parameters and the return value. Lambda receives `old` first and `new` second. This is actually not specified in the documentation. Then you need to return `true` if items are the same, so the opposite of what you're doing.

A working solution:

```kotlin
.distinctUntilChanged { old, new ->
    new - old <= 2
}
```

Comment: A tip for OP, if you use auto-complete in the IDE, it fills in the parameter names of the lambda for you, which would have prevented this mistake.